# Retrieving a lookup field or value but keeping the RecordSet updateable

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a subform which displays data from a SQL Server table which users are able to amend in realtime. This works fine. I need to display a column which returns an aggregated figure for visual display purposes only. The user doesn't need to be able to update this figure (which of course they couldn't anyway) but I need to display it for each row. What is the best way to achieve this read-only lookup field without preventing the edit/add elements of the Subform data table?

I have added the row via the RecordSource Query but that makes the dataset not updateable because of the aggregation:

```sql
 SELECT a.ActivityID, 
        a.ActivityTypeID, 
        a.ActivityName, 
        ap.DateActive, 
        ap.Points, 
        a.ActivityActive 
   FROM (ActivityPoints AS ap 
  INNER JOIN Activity AS a 
        ON a.ActivityID = ap.ActivityID) 
  INNER JOIN 
        (
             SELECT ap2.ActivityID as [ActID],
                    MAX(ap2.DateActive) as [MaxDate]            
               FROM ActivityPoints as ap2           
              GROUP BY          
                    ap2.ActivityID
        ) AS ap2
        ON ap.DateActive = ap2.MaxDate
        AND a.ActivityID = ap2.ActID
  ORDER BY 
        a.ActivityID;
```

I have also tried saving this as a query and selecting everything from it like so, but this too is not updateable:

```sql
SELECT a.ActivityID, 
       a.ActivityTypeID, 
       a.ActivityName, 
       s.DateActive, 
       s.Points, 
       a.ActivityActive
  FROM SD_Activity AS a
  LEFT JOIN SavedQuery as s
       ON s.ActivityID = a.ActivityID
```

Lastly, the last solution I have was to create a DLookup field in the ControlSource of the field on the Subform to retrieve the data from the SavedQuery. This works, but as you can imagine is incredibly resource heavy and cumbersome:

**RecordSource**

```sql
SELECT a.ActivityID,  
       a.ActivityTypeID,
       a.ActivityName, 
       a.ActivityActive
  FROM Activity AS a;
```

**ControlSource**

```vb
=DLOOKUP("[DateActive]", "[SavedQuery]", "[SavedQuery]![ActivityID] = [ActivityID]")
```

What is the best way to achieve a read-only "lookup" column in my subform data table, keeping all other fields updateable?

Answer (score 0):

There is also `DMAX` function similar to `dlookup`. Would that help?

```
DMax ( expression, domain, [criteria] )
```

[See here](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dmax.php)

Comment: Thanks - `DMax` most definitely is far faster and works better for what I need to use it for. It's still incredibly slow and very laggy when scrolling up and down the form unfortunately though.

Comment: i'd also advise indexing the `DateActive` field, if possible and see if that helps. @RazorKillBen

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it works when you perform the aggregation in a separate query. After that you can join the table with the query.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this as per my question here: "I have also tried saving this as a query and selecting everything from it like so, but this too is not updateable:" - it didn't seem to work as I thought it would if I tried that but unfortunately, no luck.